# Identifying papyrus in image from my computer

Tags: greek, text-corpus, papyrology

Digging through my computer, I found this image, named `PK8r.jpg`.

[image]

I assume `P` stands for "Papyrus" and `K` for "Köln", but I couldn't find it online, neither on [Kölner Papyri](https://papyri.uni-koeln.de/) nor as a random online image. I am guessing `r` stands for "recto", so that would be the recto of some `P. Köln 8`, except there are tons of P. Köln 8 if 8 is taken as a volume number, and apparently none (numbers start at 50 [here](http://papyri.info/search?SERIES=P.K%C3%B6ln) in the P. Köln series!). So is that "name" correct, or is there another number I'm missing after the 8? And is it known what the papyrus contains? I mean, has it been linked to something else with more text that is identifiable? With the few letters here, I doubt it is possible to conclude anything about the content from the papyrus alone…

Comment: BTW, a Google reverse image search is usually a good way to go for this kind of thing

Comment: @brianpick That's a useful piece of info. Never heard of that, just learnt how to by reading [this](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en) :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it [here](https://papyri.uni-koeln.de/stueck/tm62697). Tricky, tricky, you have to add the zeroes in front of it to pull it up.

Comment: Well done......

Comment: The link currently gives an error.

Comment: @MickG Worked fine for me. Try it more than once.

Comment: Idk what my computer was smoking when I commented, but now the link works for me too :).

Comment: @MickG It also gave me an error at one point. I don't think it was your computer, but the website instability.